# Can't generate the log file with slf4j?

Tags: maven, slf4j

I have a standard maven project and my maven settings:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Under my "resources" directory, I have the two files:
1. boot.properties:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

2. log4j2.xml

   log
           info
           error

   ```
   <Appenders>
       <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
           <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %class{36} [%L] [%M] - %msg%xEx%n" />
       </Console>

       <RollingRandomAccessFile name="INFO-LOG" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/${INFO_FILE_NAME}.log" filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/${INFO_FILE_NAME}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">
           <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %class{36} [%L] [%M] - %msg%xEx%n" />
           <Policies>
               <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512000 KB" />
           </Policies>
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
       </RollingRandomAccessFile>

       <RollingRandomAccessFile name="ERROR-LOG" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/${ERROR_FILE_NAME}.log" filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/${ERROR_FILE_NAME}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log">
           <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %class{36} [%L] [%M] - %msg%xEx%n" />
           <Policies>
               <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512000 KB" />
           </Policies>
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
       </RollingRandomAccessFile>
   </Appenders>

   <Loggers>
       <Root level="INFO" includeLocation="true">
           <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
           <appender-ref ref="INFO-LOG" />
           <appender-ref ref="ERROR-LOG" />
       </Root>
   </Loggers>
   ```

My problem is that, when I run my application, I didn't see the "log" directory and log files generated in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Slf4J doesn't provide any actual logging implementation.
It looks like you need an slf4j binding for log4j2. slf4j-simple can't read log4j2.xml

From [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-with-log4j2-logback) start off with the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The log info is printed to my console, but don't know why it didn't create the log file at all.

Comment: So the question is after I placed the log4j2.xml under /resources, is there any other configuration to do in order for it to output to a log file? Currently, I only see the logging messages on the console.

Comment: First of all I suggest to place a debugger on "logger.info()" statement and see to which underlying implementation the slf4j logger is bound. I can't say for sure what else should be done, because it really depends on your build artifact, is it a web application? is it a regular application with Method main? Is it spring boot application?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is due to access privilege in root folder.
Logger is not able to create a log folder in root directory.
You can check it yourself by trying to create a directory in root folder.
You can users path instead of root directory in log4j2.xml.